# How to change order columns and combine them together in a single pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two pandas data frames below.
How can I change the order of the columns and combine them?
Thanks!

```
+-----+---------------+-----------------+
| Id  |     Name      |      Title      |
+-----+---------------+-----------------+
| 121 | Value 2       | This is a title |
| 323 | Is a row with | Only one cell   |
+-----+---------------+-----------------+


+-----+---------------+--------+
| Id  |     Title     |  Name  |
+-----+---------------+--------+
| 443 | Title again   | Henk   |
| 454 | Just a Titile | Hertog |
+-----+---------------+--------+
```

I want a column like below ;)

```
+-----+-----------------+----------------+
| Id  |      Title      |      Name      |
+-----+-----------------+----------------+
| 121 | This is a title | Value 2        |
| 323 | Only one cell   | Is a row with  |
| 443 | Title again     | Henk           |
| 454 | Just a Titile   | Hertog         |
+-----+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Try this: `df = df[['Id', 'Title', 'Name']]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), it correct align columns names also and change order of columns by `list`:

```
cols = ['Id', 'Title', 'Name']
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)[cols]
print (df)
    Id            Title           Name
0  121  This is a title        Value 2
1  323    Only one cell  Is a row with
2  443       Title gain           Henk
3  454    Just a Titile         Hertog
```

Or first change ordering and then use `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1[cols], df2[cols]], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

`df = df[['Id', 'Title', 'Name']]`

Easy and simple indexing/selection.